# Any chance to use non QObject classes with QML

Tags: c++, qml, qobject

As of [Exposing Attributes of C++ Types to QML](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtqml/qtqml-cppintegration-exposecppattributes.html) classes used with QML have to be `QObject`s. Any chance I can use non `QObjects` s (aka POCO, not derived from `QObject`, but registered with Qt metasystem)?

If not, is there a simple generic wrapping system to make my objects QML compliant. One I can think of is to add dynamic properties to a simple `QObject`.

Or is there a way to implicitly convert to a QML compliant type so I do not need to wrap at all?

Comment: Thanks for upvoting! Have you been to Qt DevDays'13 may be on the last week (in Berlin)? Then we could have met!

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive answer. I'll leave the question open for some more days, but then likely accept your answer. I was not in Berlin, btw.

Comment: Thanks, my mail is in the profile, and I actually feel like trying to experiment on this a bit myself (if I get enough time) soon; so, if you wish, we can try some things out. The Berlin event was nice :)

Answer (score 2):

This is one hot topic actually.

I believe you may register your own PODs and pass them around ito and within the QML side (just as black boxes -- w/o any member access, have never tried that). To access the members, some get/set wrapper code could be used, either in form of methods on a QML singleton, or on a QtObject descendant effectively serving as a per-instance wrapper.

Dynamic properties are not currently supported -- you can make them work probably with some quite weird trickery, but it will not probably be worth it (but if you don't want to *bind* to properties, things will get much-much simpler, and it still will be QObjects).

Implicitly converting would mean having some sort of preprocessor (which is doable probably but would cost lots of time, and a sudecution to submit the result back into Qt (and support it for life)).

I'd go this way:

- if objects in question can be QObjects, measure the performance (and if it's ok, stick with it)
- if not, attempt passing opaque PODs by value, if it works, create wrapper scaffolding, and see if it's faster / gives better memory usage than the previous option
- if no bindings to proerties are needed, and dynamism is required, investigate a) nested QVariants b) dynamic QObject properties
- if extreme speed / mem requirements should be met, consider writing a tool that auto-generates wrappers and hooking it into the Qt project build pipeline

Thing is, custom PODs don't enjoy the same level of support the built-in do, and the standard language practices are built around manipulating garbage-collected QObject instances (passed everywhere by pointer, of course), which have watched-for-changes properties of types:

- POD
- list
- QObject
- variant (not watched for member changes, iirc)