# QML property of property of C++ object

Tags: c++, qt, qml

I am new to QML and have a problem in accessing a property.property of a C++ object:

C++, frequency and station both are Qt metatype registered objects:

```
CStation *station = new CStation(...); // QObject
CFrequency *frequency = new CFrequency(..); // QObject
QQmlContext *qmlContext = viewer.rootContext();
qmlContext->setContextProperty("myatcstation", station);
qmlContext->setContextProperty("myfrequency", frequency);
```

QML:

```
 RowLayout { ....
        TextField {
            text: myatcstation.toQString(true)
        }
    }
 ....       text: myfrequency.toQString(true)
```

This works, but when I write: `text: myatcstation.frequency.toQString(true)` I do get `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'toQString'`

`frequency` is a property of class `CStation` set as `Q_PROPERTY(CFrequency frequency READ getFrequency)`

Crosscheck in C++ works:

```
CFrequency test = station->property("frequency").value<CFrequency>();
```

-- Edit: Frank's answer --

Both classes are derived from `QObject`, and it is not as per textbook as they are made copyable. I am aware of the [Identity vs value](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/object.html#identity-vs-value) situation.

Basically frequency is a value object, but I have made it `QObject` based so I am able to use properties with it (see [Any chance to use non QObject classes with QML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19325564/any-chance-to-use-non-qobject-classes-with-qml) ). In the example, `toString` is `Q_INVOKABLE`, frequency in the non-working case returns a copy of a `QObject` derived `CFrequency` object.

-- Edit: Further findings --

When I change the frequency property to return `CFrequency*` instead of `CFrequency` it does not work either. As I get `TypeError: Cannot call method 'toQString' of undefined` the situation seems to be the same. `CFrequency` alone works, but QML does not understand that `myatcstation.frequency` is a frequency object which has `toString`.

Answer (score 1):

`CFrequency` isn't a QObject I assume, otherwise you wouldn't return it by value but by pointer. To make `toQString() callable from QML, it must be either Q_INVOKABLE or a slot, which means that CFrequency must be a QObject as well.

If a station has only one frequency, consider moving the relevant information into the station object, i.e. add the frequency information you need as properties to CStation.

To get updates when the frequency changes, consider to use a property such as `Q_PROPERTY(QString frequencyAsString READ frequencyAsString NOTIFY frequencyAsStringChanged)` instead of `toQString()`. Properties have the update mechanism "built-in" via property bindings, while there's no good way to tell QML that it should call toQString again because the frequency changed.

Comment: Good hint, added some info above. The question is, should it work if CFrequency (which is a QObject return by value) is returned as copy (even if it is not desired to copy QObjects).

Answer (score 1):

I solved a similar problem:

```
class TopObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(ValueObject* theValue ...
  ...
}

class ValueObject : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString value ...
  ...
}
```

In the main application:

```
qRegisterMetaType<ValueObject>("ValueObject");
qmlRegisterType<ValueObject>("com.name.comp", 1, 0, "ValueObject");

...->setContextProperty("topObject", new TopObject());
```

And in the qml code:

```
import com.name.comp 1.0

... {
  text: topObject.theValue.value
...
```

It needed both, returning the property (ValueObject) as pointer and registering it with qmlRegisterType.

See also [Exchange Data and Objects between C++ and QML and vice versa](http://ruedigergad.com/2011/11/13/exchange-data-and-objects-between-c-and-qml-and-vice-versa/)